# Timage - switch between images

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-10.1-berlin

Having placed an FMX Timage component on a form, would anyone know the best approach for switching/looping between x2 images in the Timage component on an interval?

Thanks,

Comment: Use a timer, when the timer fires, switch the image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use TTimer and when it fires switch the image.